How to know the expected result in Test Driven Development when using Constrained Non-Determinism without duplicating Logic
I am currently reading the (not yet completed) ebook "Test Driven Developlment - Extensive Tutorial" by Grzegorz Gałęzowski. There is a chapter featuring Mark Seeman's idea of constrained non-determinism which basically means that one should use anonymous inputs independently generated within a defined range as input for testing.
As an example, you can think of a class like
public class Division
{
    private double a, b;

    public Division(double a, double b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public double Perform() => a/b;
}

to be tested. The test would look like this:
[Fact]
public void ShouldReturnQuotientIfDenominatorNotZero()
{
    // Given
    double numerator = Any.Double();
    double denominator = Any.DoubleExcept(0);
    
    var division = new Division(numerator, denominator);

    // When
    var result = division.Perform();
    
    // Then
    Assert.AreEqual(numerator/denominator, result);
}

My problem in this very simple example is that the numerator/denominator in the Assert statement is already a duplication of the a/b in the Division's Perform method.
How would one do this in a real world scenario? Having the same logic in the test and in the implementation obviously does not make sense.

This goes better with a different way of testing - where you're not testing for specific outputs, but for things you want to be true of any implementation. E.g. suppose Scramble(string) function should return some random-looking output, and suppose one of the requirements is that the scrambled output should be the same for the same input strings. You could write a test that has a prepared input string & checks for an expected output string, but then you'd have to change the test every time you change the scrambling algorithm. Instead, call Scramble twice and assert if the two outputs match.

That looks a lot like property based testing, a kind of fuzzing used by test frameworks like QuickCheck (Haskell) or Hypothesis (Python). It's easy to accidentally define tautological properties that always pass, but even "complicated algo is equivalent to simple obvious algo" is a useful property. For division over rational numbers or integers, forall a: forall b ≠ 0: division(a * b, b) == a would be a more useful property (constructing test inputs that are trivial to verify), but unfortunately using floats makes good tests very difficult (rounding, error accumulation, nans, infs, …).

The issue you are showing here (as well as Mark Seeman with his Invert example) is IMHO not mainly caused by the use of constrained non-deterministic test data.
It is caused by the simplicity of those two examples - the fact the tested functionality is in both cases available as single language or library operation (/  or string.Reverse). For such kind of function, the most simple test is probably the duplication of the tested functionality, hence it obviously makes sense.
However, when you create a real-world program with more realistic features in your classes, it is unlikely that your code will just duplicate existing operations or library functions one-to-one. Real code will usually have more complex operations, and several - if not most - of them will allow verification of the correctness of output to a certain input without fully duplicating the tested operation.
For example, let us take a Sort function - you may constrain some non-deterministic input to be a certain number of different values. Then you can easily verify for the result

if the values are ordered in the right direction
if the resultset contains all the input values (and no others)

Other ways of implementing tests may involve approaches like

verifying a certain assignment happens for the given (random) input values when a certain operation is called - you won't implement the assignment twice, but verify by the assignment by retrieval
testing if some kind of reversal operation of the tested operation brings back the original input (for example, numerator == denominator * result). This works when there is such a reversal operation, ideally one which is simpler than the tested operation
testing if a different implementation of the tested operation brings the same results. One may come up with somple simpler implementation which is less performant, or a simpler implementation which works only with the constrained test data - because of the constraints.

So in short: how to come up with a test using "unknown" input data (or "anonymous" data, as Seeman calls it)  which does not duplicate the tested function's logic depends heavily on the function. In trivial cases where the implementation of a function can be as simple as a single arithmetic operation or string statement, duplicating that statement can make sense, because there is simply (pun intended) no simpler, more "trustworthy" approach. But for anything more complex, testing becomes more effective when one finds a test which is simpler to write and read than the code in the SUT.

"In cases where the implementation of a function is as simple as a single arithmetic operation or string statement duplicating that statement can make sense." You don't say why.

@Ewan because the test isn't driven by the code. It's driven by the requirements. The test is under no obligation to consider how the code was written. You can write the test before the code. And the code only has to satisfy the tests demands. Trivially duplicating an operation may make you feel silly. Not making you feel silly is not a requirement. The point isn't the duplication. It's whether the test reflects the requirement.

@DocBrown if it was obvious I wouldn't have to spend so much time arguing about it. You're absolutely right. So please preach it.

@candied_orange: I already edited my answer a bit, hope it is clearer now.

"because the test isn't driven by the code. It's driven by the requirements. The test is under no obligation to consider how the code was written". I think that is exactly the point! The test does not duplicate the implementation but the final implementation might duplicate the test. This plus the fact that there might be other ways to verify the output in real life makes this the correct answer in my opinion.


How would one do this in a real world scenario?

I'd do it exactly like this.

Having the same logic in the test and in the implementation obviously does not make sense.

Yes it does. Here's why:
I can now refactor Division to a completely different implementation. One that doesn't even use the ALU if I like. I can test whole new division algorithm implementations all without needing to touch this test.
Some may look at this example like it's too simple. Well, if anything, it wasn't the test that was too simple. It was the code under test. I like simple tests. Give me more.
Always remember, the point of a test isn't to prove the code does what it says it does. Or that it hasn't changed. It's to prove you're getting the behavior you expected.
The logic of the code being tested can't invalidate the test. Only a change in requirements can. It's not the tests fault if your code makes you feel silly.
Stop thinking about how to test the code. Think about what code the test requires.

MS's actual example is Invert(x) which reverses strings and parses and inverts numbers. His test splits this into two, but simply rearranging the test code duplicates the test subject. Any mistake in the code, would also exist in the test. Which is what you are trying to avoid with pre calculate, hard coded input and expected results

@Ewan pre calculated how? Using what? What is this magical process that can only cornubite to testing if you do it by hand?

You can't really refactor the Perform method to do anything else. You could do it with a fuzzy test, but with strict equality test it is likely to be impossible. Because your  implementation is likely to fail on different platforms. Testing division, or any other platform dependent operation just doesn't make sense. And that's what I read behind "too simple" argument.

yeah by hand, signed off as correct and then used to test your implementation is correct?

I feel that your explanation of why to dupe the logic in the test is lacking. If you have one implementation then your test says "A must do what A does", if you have two it says "B must do what A does", but you never confirmed A was correct.

@Freakish A strict equality test would only be impossible if either doubles inputs were measurements or differing lossy conversions. Here they aren't. Without that double division is completely deterministic. Sorry. You've been lied to about when you can compare doubles. Never is the wrong answer. You're ALU isn't the only way to divide doubles.

Well, this all would be true if avoiding division by zero was all you need to do to avoid NaNs. Not sure if Any.Double() ever produces a NaN on its own. NaN's aren't this easy to compare. Also aren't very standardized.

+1 for “It's to prove you're getting the behavior you expected.”  While we typically want and hope that maps to the “correct answer” that isn’t always the case and of course that can’t really be verified. While acting as expected is always verifiable. Subtle difference but useful.

@candied_orange where did you find me mentioning determinism or conversions in my comment? That's completely not the point. The point is that there is more than single "floating point arithmetic". Different hardware may do it differently, not everything follows IEE 754. I don't know if C# (is that C# btw?) guarantees a particular representation over all supported platforms. If not, then of course there is no guarantee that such test passes. And you have to write tests per platform. Of course noone will do that.

@freakish you're right, there is more than a single implementation. Doesn't mean the test is wrong. The test is insisting that whatever Division is implementing should match whatever / is implementing. That would only be wrong if it's not the requirement.

@candied_orange yes, and you say that you can reimplement Perform with a "completely different implementation". Which is completely unrealistic, and literally noone would do that. The only sensible way of implementing it is through /. That's what I've been saying from the beginning. And that's why this test doesn't make any sense.

@freakish no one would do that? How do you think we got / in the first place?

@candied_orange I don't understand the question. Are you asking about mathematics behind it? In practice it comes from hardware. Yes, hardware creators test their hardware. But they don't write tests per platform, why would they care about other platforms? I doubt even a single compiler software tests division. But I'll be more than happy to see such tests.

@freakish I would be surprised as well. Compilers didn't give us floating point division. You don't need a compiler to use it. Doesn't mean it didn't need testing. Anyway, even if this particular software didn't need this test it doesn't mean this approach is wrong. We were never testing that / worked. We were assuming it worked and showing that Division provided the same behavior. If that isn't needed It means the software never needed the Division class. Because if there is no requirement, then the behavior we're testing isn't needed. Which is what I've been saying from the start.

@jmoreno thank you. I think of being correct is a rare and fleeting state. Achieve it and even if we change nothing, the world around us will change and suddenly we're wrong again.

You're touching on a good example of why I think that not controlling your concrete inputs is not always helpful on its own - it requires you to derive your assert values, which means calculating them.
When your real logic already performs the shortest calculation path between input and output, the test logic that derives the assert value effectively has to reinvent the logic, which is not helpful.
An example of what is not the shortest path would be if your operations first finds the quotient, and then generates that many table entries. Doing the division isn't the main thing here, asserting that the correct amount of table rows are generated is the important part, which is something you can shortcut by just counting them.
At its very core, you are touching on a theme very much related to the P=NP problem (link): can you you confirm the validity of a result faster than the original calculation that you're validating?
In this case it's about code duplication instead of algorithmic complexity, but the blocker issue is the same, i.e. the similar-if-not-identical paths of performing a calculation and verifying said calculation.
As per suggestion in comments, the link to P=NP I'm pointing out is thematic, not perfectly identical.
In my opinion, it makes more sense here to control your input and design a few examples where you've vetted for yourself that the assert value matches your expectations of what happens based on the input.
Your test is effectively a fuzz test. This has some value, but I wouldn't say that it's objectively superior to controlled input/output testing.
Fuzz testing is great when:

You want to additionally run these tests in order to discover bugs that a person would not have thought of. A simple example here would be testing a string input for unusual characters - developers often forget about those.
You're dealing with an input type that has a wide variation on possible inputs that are meaningfully different from one another, that it's impractical to manually generate all these test cases, and you could more easily rely on a "run many random examples" approach that are statistically likely to cover the spread of possible scenarios.

Using your specific example of division, this is an operation that does not change based on whether you use 100, 200, 300, or any other number. The only real question here is with the edge cases - zeroes and negative values come to mind.
That's two edge cases, which is easier to write manually and it avoid the code duplication issue. Fuzz testing here makes little sense - perhaps unless it was a performance test where you want to confirm that the size of the number does not impact the performance, which can be different based on the method of division you're employing (e.g. if you were to repeatedly subtract the denominator from the numerator, like primary school children are sometimes taught to do).

This answers reads like you did not take the time to read Mark Seeman's blog post. His motivation for choosing constrained random values has nothing to do with fuzz tests.

I don't think P=NP is directly relevant, though tests benefit when the logic to assert outputs is simpler than the system under test. Often, this simplicity can be achieved by constructing example inputs with a certain structure. Simplicity doesn't mean "faster". For example, I once wrote tests for an efficient path finding algorithm by checking that it found a solution equivalent to an obviously correct brute force search.

@amon: to be fair - after reading the P=NP paragraph (and the following sentences) twice, I think Flater just used this as an example for a somewhat comparable problem - he is surely aware that "simpler" does not mean "faster". Still, since first reading gave me the wrong impression he could have meant that. I would recommend a rewording to make the difference between P=NP and the actual problem more apparent..

@amon: What DocBrown said. I was pointing at a thematic link more so than an identical problem, i.e. that the derivation logic that generates the test's asserted value is not inherently simpler than the real logic that you're testing in the first place - rendering it to generally become an act of WET.

@DocBrown: The blog post does not touch on the concern that me and OP seem to be focusing on, i.e. the logic duplication required to find the expected value, based on an unknown input value (regardless of the randomness being constrained as needed). It seems solely focus on concerns about the input value (and its source), rather than the knock-on effect this has on how the test will need to come up with the expected value.

@DocBrown As to the subsequent blog post about derived values, I find it a forced argument. I'm referring to "there's no apparent relationship between the input (ploeh) and the output (42)", which is IMO a disingenuous claim as they actively removed any sensible context from e.g. the test method name, even though all other example (that work in their favor) are given clear names to help make sense of the test. Additionally, the relationship between input and output in most business cases is not one of algorithmic calculation but one of arbitrary business requirements, which [..]

[..] means that in order to be able to derive the expected output, that arbitrary business logic needs to be duplicated. The only real use case I see for this argument is for a specific operation that has several ways of doing the same thing, and the choice between those approaches is made for reasons unrelated to the test itself. That is to say, the test is validating the correct value, and you're happy to use a simpler and potentially less performant method to find the expected value; whereas the "real" code being tested does it a different (e.g. more complicated and performant) way.

@DocBrown Perhaps a more succinct way of phrasing it is that every example I've seen in Mark Seeman's test snippets immediately reveals the implementation of the unit under test, rather than its public behavior; which in my opinion is antithetical to the purpose of unit testing (and that is including white box testing - I'm not restricting this to black box testing). This is an exercise in writing the same logic twice and catching regressions on the assumption that you only broke one of them in a single go and have the unchanged version call you out on it by failing the test.

@Flater I agree, dunno why people are saying it makes sense to dupe the logic under test. I didn't think it worth bringing up, seems like the OP says, obviously bad.

@Flater: (so much response for a single comment of mine - must have hit a nerve ;-) I fully agree that writing the same logic twice is clearly against the idea of a useful unit test (except when the tested code is so trivial there is no real alternative to it). I also agree that Seeman has chosen his examples a little bit too simplistific and some more context would help Still, I think Seeman has a point with his idea, which has IMHO not nothing to do with fuzz testing, should be explained with a better example. But IMHO the comment section is not the right place to discuss it any further.

... maybe someone writes another question about Seeman's blog post, challenging his idea of constrained non-determinism ? Still, I guess it is hard to find a question which would not be closed as "opinionated".

No nerve hit, just not something that I could accurately counter in a single comment :)

Ooof.. hmm. yeah. Basically I think the blog is giving bad, or at least confusing advice.
So my reading of this is that Mark Seemann has two ideas which are getting mixed up.

Constrained Non-Determinism.
This means to avoid using hardcoded values in your tests, instead replacing them with semi random data.


This practice is used commonly in tests to:

Avoid collision with other tests
Avoid false positives because you read from a database which already had the data
Generate more realistic data, for example with "john smith" rather than "test1234 test345643"

This is fine, and considered good practice. However, I'm not sure if these practices are what he is thinking of.

Derived Values Ensure Executable Specification
Here is is doing what you say, expectedValue = numerator / denominator The argument is that this makes the test the documentation for the method. ie this method is supposed to divide the numbers and the test clearly states that.


In his example his class has two branches, so he is able to say hes not replicating the functionality of the subject under test in the tests. But a simple code rearrangement and he will literally have the exact same code in his test and implementation.
I can't see how this would work in real life. In fact it's normally something you want to be flagging up as a problem of "testing the mock" where you are recreating functionality in your tests in mock form.
Some of the other answers are to me surprisingly saying that duplicating the code functionality in the test is "Obviously Good", so maybe it's worth saying why it's bad.

In TDD you are supposed to write you test before you write the code. It would be next to impossible to proceed if you have to write the functionality in your test, before you write the functionality

Most functionality you are developing, won't duplicate existing functionality in the language. If it did, you wouldn't be writing it.

Your test wont be the specification. The whole aim is to have tests which say "the Divide function divides numbers" but actually your test ends up saying "the Divide function does the same as the divide operator". A subtle difference which you won't notice until the divide operator does something weird.

Specs are written by humans, they aren't written in code. So you are going to have a description of the functionality and a bunch of examples in your Spec. eg. "The cost should be the total divided by the discount, rounded up to the nearest penny, example ...."

The most obvious. When you only have one implementation, your tests no longer test, you just say "implementation A's results must be the same as implementation A".


@Filip makes a good point, in that if your code offers the reverse functionality you can define your test in those terms. This achieves the objective of making the test the spec, but without reimplementation.
ie
subject.Save(randomData);
var actual = subject.Load(randomData.Id)
Assert(actual == randomData);

Is something I do all the time, my test is saying "The subject must be able to retrieve what was saved", we don't care what was saved.
PS. This is one reason why I hate Entity Framework, as it's caching mechanism means these tests always pass. But it's a good lesson to learn that sometimes what you are testing can't be defined within the confines of the class under test.

Actually 1, according to Seeman: "While this technique causes input to become non-deterministic, I always pick the non-deterministic value-generating algorithm in such a way that it creates 'nice' values; I call this principle Constrained Non-Determinism. Values are carefully generated to stay far away from any boundary conditions that may cause the SUT to behave differently in each test run." It's not just avoiding hardcoded values. It's controlling the random so it fits the need.

yes, thats what i said

You need to think about why you've written the Division class/function in the first place. Then you can test that it is meeting those needs. As an example, you may be using it to find out how to evenly spread some resource among some consumers. "Evenly" here means we haven't oversubscribed to resources and there's at most one extra resource per consumer. So the test might look like this:
[Fact]
public void SplitsEvenly()
{
    // Given
    double resources = Any.DoubleExcept(0);
    double consumers = Any.PositiveDouble();
    
    var spreader = new Division(resources, consumers);

    // When
    var resPerCon = spreader.Perform();
    
    // Not oversubscribed
    Assert.LessEqual(resPerCon*consumers, resources);

    // Not wasting resources
    Assert.GreaterEqual((resPerCon+1)*consumers, resources);
}


First, you want reproducible non-determinism. Say your real code gets one in a million cases wrong, you run a test, and it fails. Now what? You want to be able to run exactly the same test with the same data so you can find the bug. (Of course your test with 1000 cases would run without failure thousand times, so you needed non-determinism to have a chance to get a failure. This also demonstrates the need to fix all failures because otherwise you’ll never notice that failure).
Second, he wrote a test case that basically said “do X using a function in the code you want to ship, do the same X with code inside the unit test, check if the outcomes are the same”. You run into problems if the spec for X can be easily misunderstood, or if X has an implementation that is obvious but incorrect, so both codes produce the same incorrect result. No matter where your test cases come from, that is a problem.
If possible you shouldn’t check that two sets of code produce the same result, but that one set of code produces an outcome meeting requirements. For example, for a sorting function you would generate a sorted array, rearrange it more or less randomly, call your sorting code and verify that the output is the original array.

Some obvious truth's in here, but I fail to see how this gives an answer to what was asked.

Yes, I also think that reproducibility is an issue but that's another story.

In the case of testing a division operator if you use the division operator then its, as you rightly said, just duplicating the logic. Its no testing, at all.
To do any test you have to have two separate things that you compare. If you have only one thing then you cannot test it.
In school your teacher tested you by comparing your answers with the right answers in her head. She did not test you by comparing your answers with your answers.
The right answers have to come from outside the tests. You can hardcode it but your question exclude that. The only valid way then is to know other operations/logic that you know produce the right result.
So, in absence of hardcoding right values to compare result of your logic with (you know that 15 is the right result when 180 is divided by 12, the right result 15 didnt come from your logic) the only other valid way to test is to have an alternate logic (such as left shifting one bit is same as dividing by 2).
